# Return from foreach loop

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I'm new to PHP.  I have a dummy database with three users and I want to insert their keys and values into an array.

```
$result_set=$database->GeneralQuery("SELECT * FROM users");
$the_object_array=array();
while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set)) {
   foreach($row as $key => $value){
      $the_object_array[$key] = $value;             
   }
}
print_r($the_object_array);
```

Which returns:-

```
Array ( [id] => 3 [username] => anne [password] => 123 [first_name] => Anne [last_name] => Baird ).....
```

In other words only the last user in the database table with keys and values.

How can i get `print_r($the_object_array)` to print out all three users with keys and values

Comment: `while ($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set)) {
$the_object_array[] = $row;
}
print_r($the_object_array);`

Comment: Thank you very much for your prompt response.....can't believe I didn't try that myself!

Comment: Yes...that works..thanks again

Comment: Anant....I'm new to this...how do I "mark the answer"?

Comment: Bairdy you are able to see one tick mark beside answer. just tick that one

Answer (score 1):

Try following code

```
$result_set=$database->GeneralQuery("SELECT * FROM users");
$the_object_array=array();
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result_set)) { 
   $the_object_array[] = $row; 
} 
print_r($the_object_array);
```

Comment: Wow!   Overwhelmed by the help you guys have given....problem solved....onward and upwards!

Comment: I'm sorry about that.  As I said I'm new to this and didn't understand the system - I'm sure you were a newbie once so please - I won't make that mistake again

Comment: @Bairdy  you need to mark one person answer as accepted (by checking comments as well as answer).

Answer (score 0):

try to something like this....

You have remove key in foreach...like this `$the_object_array[] = $value1;`

```
$the_object_array=array();
    $row = array(
            '1'=>array(
                'id' =>'3',
                'name'=>'test'
            ),
            '2'=>array(
                'id' =>'3' ,
                'name'=>'test1'
            )
        );
    foreach($row as $key => $value){
        foreach ($value as $key1 => $value1) {
            $the_object_array[] = $value1;
        }
    }
    print_r($the_object_array);
```